# How to declare the return of `emplace()` of an instantiated `std::set`?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

## Scenario

1. I have a class template:

   ```
   template<class idxT>
   class SimpleGraph {
   private:
     // ...
     std::set<std::pair<idxT,idxT>> edgeSet;
     // ...
     void addEdge(idxT a, idxT b);
     // ...
   }
   ```
2. I need to use the return of `edgeSet.emplace(a,b)` inside `addEdge()`, which is denoted as `r` in the following.
3. The declaration and the assignment of `r` need to be separated since the value of `a` and `b` is determined by a if-else statement. Thus, I cannot use

   ```
   auto r = edgeSet.emplace(a,b);
   ```
4. I tried the following strategies but neither is successful. The first one is

   ```
   std::pair<decltype(edgeSet)::iterator,bool> r;
   // some code
   r = edgeSet.emplace(a,b);
   ```

   The second one is

   ```
   // inside class template
   typedef std::set<std::pair<idxT,idxT>> EdgeSetType;
   EdgeSetType edgeSet;

   // inside definition of `addEdge()`
   std::pair<EdgeSetType::iterator,bool> r;
   // some code
   r = edgeSet.emplace(a,b);
   ```

## Question

How can I declare the return of `edgeSet.emplace(a,b)`?

## Update 1: a verifiable example for the first trial

```
#include <set>      // set
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <iostream>

template<class idxT>
class SimpleGraph {
public:
  void test(void);

private:
  std::set<std::pair<idxT,idxT>> edgeSet;
  void addEdge(idxT a, idxT b);
};

template<class idxT>
void SimpleGraph<idxT>::test(void) {
  addEdge(1,2);
  addEdge(1,2);
}

template<class idxT>
void SimpleGraph<idxT>::addEdge(idxT a, idxT b) {

  std::pair<decltype(edgeSet)::iterator,bool> r;

  if (a < b) {
    r = edgeSet.emplace(a,b);
  }
  else {
    r = edgeSet.emplace(a,b);
  }
  if (!r.second) {
    std::cerr << "Error on (" << a << ',' << b <<"): "
              << "mutiple edges are not allowed for a simple graph.\n";
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  SimpleGraph<int> graph;
  graph.test();
}
```

clang complains that

```
test.cpp:24:13: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?
  std::pair<decltype(edgeSet)::iterator,bool> r;
```

See also [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/795997b67e54ccd4) for the compile-time error generated by gcc.

Comment: Can't reproduce, both solutions [work for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca276bdbef42bab0). Can you show us the exact error message, and a [mcve] that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Regarding point 3: I do not see how the presence of an if-else statement prevents the use of `auto` after the statement, nor why the if-else statement could not be relegated to a separate function. Perhaps the requested minimal, complete, and verifiable example should include an if-else demonstrating this?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thx. A verifiable example is added.

Comment: And what do you mean by "not successful"? If you get compiler errors, please paste those as well.

Comment: And what happens if you take the compiler's advice and add the `typename` keyword immediately before `decltype`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clang++ compiler is actually hinting at the solution with "did you forget 'typename'?"

Since `decltype(edgeSet)` is type-dependent (it indirectly depends on template parameter `idxT`), a compiler can't just look it up when it first parses the template, so C++ says to assume any name following `decltype(edgeSet)::` is a variable or function.  Since it's really a type, you need to tell C++ so, using the keyword `typename`:

```
std::pair<typename decltype(edgeSet)::iterator,bool> r;
```

More details are at the answers to the question [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Or, note that any valid expression at all can be used inside `decltype`.  (And it's an unevaluated context, meaning that if you use function calls, implicit conversions, etc. no functions will actually be called for that expression.)  So you could also just do:

```
decltype(edgeSet.emplace(a,b)) r;
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, I find these two concepts—[static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) and [dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)—are helpful.